# Many intro questions re ubuntu on nexus 7; dual-boot, capabilities

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

I seem to have thought Ubuntu on the nexus 7 was further along than it is. I have many questions. Here are some.

IRC - where is the discussion of Ubuntu on my device taking place? It is not in any free node channel I can find. Eg, android nexus Ubuntu ubuntu-quality sdx-developers android-root

When I use the nexus 7 with Ubuntu need I have an external monitor?
May I use a mouse and keyboard at the same time? With Bluetooth?
Can I do YouTube? Flash? What apps/programs are there for it?
Can I run a printer? External optical drive? Use VLC? Play a movie from an external SD card?
What kind of battery time can I expect? With or w/o WiFi?
How much space does the JB is take up on the device? How much space does Ubuntu take up?

Glad I have the 32G. Is this model completely supported? 
I don't use it now but is the Sim card supported?-:-)

Is there a better place to ask this?
Thanks.

---- I do not understand the fork of ubuntuforums.org and askubuntu.com 
I wanted to use the tag of nexus or nexus7 but I do not have enough "reputations" here though I have used Ubuntu forums many times.
---- I am so disappointed with JB which is impotent about simple things. There is no undo while editing. Oops I touched and a para vanished.

Answer (score 2):

> IRC - where is the discussion of Ubuntu on my device taking place? It is not in any free node channel I can find. Eg, android nexus Ubuntu ubuntu-quality sdx-developers android-root

You can find the details of that here:

- http://www.jonobacon.org/2012/10/26/ubuntu-core-on-the-nexus-7/

> When I use the nexus 7 with Ubuntu need I have an external monitor?

Do you *need*?, not really. You can just use the Tablet's screen.

> May I use a mouse and keyboard at the same time? With Bluetooth?

I'm not sure if Bluetooth works yet, though you can search for questions here.

> Can I do YouTube? Flash? What apps/programs are there for it?

You can use the HTML 5 trial of YouTube, or if Chrome is available for ARM use that. You can install and use software only compiled for ARM.

> Can I run a printer? External optical drive? Use VLC? Play a movie from an external SD card?

You can use a WiFi printer, if there are accessories for the Nexus 7 that add the USB host capability might be worth a try. You can play media just fine.

> What kind of battery time can I expect? With or w/o WiFi?

They're working on that quite hard, I'd expect some 4 hours, then again you can search for questions on that here.

> How much space does the JB is take up on the device? How much space does Ubuntu take up?

You can check that on the Settings in JB, the Ubuntu image for the Nexus 7 is 576M.

> I do not understand the fork of ubuntuforums.org and askubuntu.com

Not a fork, term doens't apply here anyways. AskUbuntu is part of StackExchange, unrelated to Ubuntu Forums.

Answer (score 1):

There is a surprising amount of information on the official [Ubuntu Wiki regarding the Nexus 7](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7).

If you look at the sub-pages at the bottom, you will find links to a lot of the answers you are looking for:

- There is no video output on the Nexus 7 so external monitors are not possible but remote desktop is an option.
- Built in bluetooth does not work under 13.04 yet. USB bluetooth keyboard and mouse is possible through kernel bluetooth modules and the gnome applet.
- Adobe Flash Player is not ported to Linux for ARM architechtures. But sites like Youtube and many others are slowly migrating to HTML5, so you could still watch most videos.
- With a USB host cable Ubuntu will recognise devices like flash drives/SDcard readers, printers, webcams etc.
- Battery life will be less than optimal as the whole project is steel deep into development. You can expect the device to run slower, be resource heavy (especially because of Unity) and as a result use a lot more energy. Results will vary.

Look around on the wiki, check out the development process. Support may be minimal because the team is still working very hard on making it work. Still, try it out, report any bugs you come across and share your impressions.

Comment: Check out Uri Herrera's answer as well :)